# How do I clear the print Queue on Windows 10 on STARTUP

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, printing, printer

We have windows 10 machines running 1803.
We need to have the print queue purged on EVERY start up.

The print spooler is set to manual.
We have a powershell script scheduled through task scheduler to run a powershell script on both Startup and User Login as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Program/script:
Powershell
Add Arguments (optional): -File "C:\production\Printer Queue Clear\printqueueClear.ps1"

The script in question (net stop spooler is redundant if the service is set to manual start, I know)

```
net stop spooler

Remove-Item C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\* -Force

net start spooler
```

The issue: if a job is queued with the USB connected printer unplugged from the computer, the computer is shut off (with print jobs still in the queue), the printer is reconnected, and then the computer is started, the print jobs all get sent through as soon as the user starts logging in. For compliance reasons, we can't have this happen.

The real question is why is the print spooler spitting out the queued jobs if: 1. it's set to manual
2. the code in question is only starting the spooler after the printer spool drive is purged.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure of the significance of the spooler service being set to manual. Windows is capable of starting services (on demand) without your intervention.

It sounds like the easiest way to solve the scenario described is to run the script on shutdown or logoff, rather than on startup or login.

Additionally, you could disable the print spooler service on shutdown or logoff and only enable it after you perform some task on startup or login, if there is a scenario I’m not aware of.

Comment: The intent was that the spooler wouldn't kick off until we told it to (manual)

We're doing a shutdown script, but that doesn't cover the use case of if someone snuffs the life out of the laptops by holding the power button to shut them down, hence trying to do them on start up. Perhaps I'll see if I can run the script after some other task after startup, just delay the whole process a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't work. Try this if it's truly set to manual:

```
net stop spooler
Remove_Item $env:windir\System32\spool\PRINTERS\* -Force
net start spooler
```

Comment: How is $env:windir different from C:\WINDOWS?

Comment: For some reason his didn't work for me.

Comment: Remove_Item is throwing an error as an invalid cmdlet.
Tried it with Remove-Item, still didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Typo error in code, should be a *`-`* minus not a *`_`* underscore in `Remove-Item`
working code: (but in powershell, not cmd):

```
net stop spooler
Remove-Item $env:windir\System32\spool\PRINTERS\* -Force
net start spooler
```

Comment: The code in the question does not have an underscore.